# How to disable mod_deflate in apache2?

Tags: apache, apache2, mod-deflate

How can I disable mod_deflate in Apache2

- For files in a specific directory

OR

- For all files that have extension of, for example .py?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could set the [environment variable *no-gzip*](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html#enable) for that directory/type of file:

```
# for URL paths that begin with "/foo/bar/"
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/foo/bar/ no-gzip=1

# for files that end with ".py"
<FilesMatch \.py$>
    SetEnv no-gzip 1
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: can I do it in .htaccess file inside that folder?

Comment: @wakandan Yes, if your `<Directory>` configuration in your main `httpd.conf` contains `AllowOverride All`.

Answer (score 3):

Quote from: [scottlinux.com](https://scottlinux.com/2012/09/13/disable-http-compression-in-apache/)

**Disable Compression**:
To disable compression in Apache, typically you just need to disable the module mod_deflate...

Debian/Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo a2dismod deflate
Module deflate disabled.
Run '/etc/init.d/apache2 restart' to activate new configuration!

$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this is a general solution, but it worked for me at least, to turn of mod_deflate for .py-files within a .htaccess file in a certain folder:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "\.py$" no-gzip dont-vary
```

Comment: worked perfectly. I prefer a one-liner when debugging