# Streaming/Partial Results Through Tastypie

Tags: python, django, http, rest, tastypie

Is there a way to stream/return partial results through tastypie ([it seems to be possible in Django in general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922874/how-to-stream-an-httpresponse-with-django)). I have an API that needs to do a bunch of requests to external services in order to produce a result. The requests to external services will take a varying amount of time to return. Rather than having the users of the API wait for all the external services to be done, I'd like to return partial results as soon as they are available. How would you go about doing this? Is this against RESTful principles?

Comment: If the data takes a long time to return, say greater than 10 seconds then why not just treat them as jobs. These jobs will run and then store the results in a database and then the client can make a second request to get their data from these external services. But, this may be more work for what your system requires.

Comment: @sean I have considered that. The request would come in, add that to a job queue, which would then be fulfilled by a worker, and results stored in the DB. The problem is that the main use of this will be search, so it poses a couple of questions: 1) the user experience will not be great if the user has to be notified that "hey, we found what you were looking for, 10 seconds ago", although as time goes by and the DB grows there will be fewer "misses". 2) It could be split into two requests, but how long will all the queueing-dequeuing and DB writes take? Fast enough?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, it depends on what broker you use as well as the storage mechanism that you use. Using something like RabbitMQ would be very ideal for your queuing and dequeuing. As far as the storing of the results mongo may be fast enough, but I am not entirely sure onto the actual speeds as I have not had a lot of experience setting up and tuning mongo.