# How to use a progress bar to show python function progress in Django?

Tags: django

I created a website where a user uploads videos and I process the video frame by frame with a python function. In this function, I know how many frames I've already processed. And I want to show the progress to users in a progress bar. I googled a lot, but almost all progress bars are for uploading, so how can I implement this? Thanks!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922874/how-to-stream-an-httpresponse-with-django . A simple way would be to write current progress into db or session, and have separated ajax call pull the progress once every X seconds.

Answer (score 8):

I wrote a [demo](https://github.com/sunshineatnoon/Django-Celery-Example), in case this may help someone else.