# using while loop jinja inside django for displaying the data from requests

Tags: django, while-loop, jinja2

i could not find any documentation for while loop in jinja,
is there any way we can create an infinite loop in jinja, i am using django framework. 
i want to request for data and keep updating the data in side the webpage.

in views have

```
 r = requests.get(URL).json()

 def index(request): 
  context = {'R' : r}
  return render(request,'detail.html',context)
```

in the html i want something like this

```
{{ while ture}}
{{ R }}
```

Comment: What you are asking is not easily achievable (and very likely not what you want), but if you are sure you are on the right track can start here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922874/how-to-stream-an-httpresponse-with-django