# Show file contents to html page in django

Tags: python, django, subprocess

I am running one shell script from django views.py. Below is the code:

```
def result(request):
   if request.method=="POST":
       process=subprcoess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprcoess.PIPE, stderr=subprcoess.PIPE, universal_newlies=True)  
       while process.poll() is None:
           print(process.communicate()[0]) 
           continue 
   return render(request, 'result.html')
```

Now here can able to get logs on file, instead directly need to redirect to html page.

Could anyone please help here?

Thank You.

Comment: This subprocess may run up to 15-20,  this output needs to be on html page as subprocess progresses

Comment: I would rather run it in separated thread and write in file, and browser would have to use JavaScript and run periodically `fetch()` to ask server for new data from file.

Comment: [python - How to stream an HttpResponse with Django - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922874/how-to-stream-an-httpresponse-with-django)