# Disable Gzip Compression in .htaccess file

Tags: gzip

I have tried using the following code but my website is still compressed using gzip:

```
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$$ no-gzip dont-vary
```

How can I disable gzip compressions?

Comment: If you're naming the file ".httpaccess" instead of ".htaccess", that might be your problem right there.

Comment: @Sneftel renamed file but still website is using gzip compression

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable mod\_deflate in apache2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922934/how-to-disable-mod-deflate-in-apache2)

Comment: @guilhermeNascimento I tried that solution but it is not working for me, I have simple html files...

Comment: "html files" or "odp files"? Clear "cache" in your browser

Comment: @guilhermeNascimento html files like index.html, about.html etc. I am sure it is not "cache" because I am using an external tool to verify

Comment: your problem is with "ODP files" or "HTML files"? Post fully "htaccess"

Comment: @guilhermeNascimento I dont have any odp files in my website. Updating questions

Comment: @guilhermeNascimento If you know what I'm doing wrong, please post answer and I will glady accept it! I am trying to remove gzip compressions from my website which is made up to of html files

Comment: Use `<FilesMatch RegExp>`, It is also likely that there are more setting up for your .htaccess file that you have not posted, or other .htaccess file out of this folder (one level up). Check all this.

Answer (score 7):

Put this code in the htaccess file and save it.It worked for me.Disabled gzip compression.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [NS,E=no-gzip:1,E=dont-vary:1]
```

Thanks

Comment: Where will be insert this above coding in htaccess file, Can you write a full structure of this one.I wrote <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [NS,E=no-gzip:1,E=dont-vary:1] .... this is right . it is not working for me / please can you help me

Comment: put inside this: <ifModule mod_gzip.c>