# The 1MB file is load like a 9.0KB file with my server on Chrome

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http-headers, compression

I try to make a speedtest with a 1 mo file on my webserver. 
The file is call with ajax request but when I call the 1mo file on Google Chrome the size downloaded is 9.0KB. 
I think is because on the header "Accept-Encoding" is set to "gzip,deflate,sdch"

How I can set the Accept-Encoding to none to download a real 1mo file ?

the file is name **1mo.file**

**javascript**

```
  $(function () {
        console.log('DOM READY');
        $('#result').append('DOM READY<br>');
        var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * 1000);

        $.ajax({
          url: "1mo.file?"+rand,
        }).then(function () {
            console.log('then');
            $('#result').append('AJAX CALL<br>');
        }).done(function() {
         console.log( "done" );
        $('#result').append( "AJAX DONE<br>" );
        });
        console.log('SCRIPT FINISH');
        $('#result').append('SCRIPT FINISH<br>');
    });
```

**html**

```
<b>speed test :</b><br>
<div id="result"></div>
```

**.htaccess**

```
# for files that end with ".file"
<FilesMatch \.file$>
    SetEnv no-gzip 1
</FilesMatch>
```

You can see the script run on http://intuitisoft.com/apps/speedtest/

Comment: Check that answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922934/how-to-disable-mod-deflate-in-apache2/1923028#1923028 it may be enough in your case

Comment: @regilero I add the code `<FilesMatch \.file$>
    SetEnv no-gzip 1
</FilesMatch>` to the .htaccess but nothing change.